# Replace div on hover (div rollover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div with different data. I want to replace div with other on hover.

I can do this in CSS but my data have images and links. so i use image in css i can not put

```html
<a href=""></a>
```

on for image.
also i have 4 different images in a dive. 
so i want that when use hover that area my first div should be replaced with 2nd div.

Thank you

Comment: Please show your code. We can't debug what we can't see.

Comment: Where are the codes We can't read your mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No example given so i'm assuming.

HTML

```
<div id="div1">Some data</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Some other data</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery)

```
$("#div1").on('mouseover', function() {
    $("#div2").show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This is not tested so try it out an see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javacript you can do it like this.

You can change the content of the divs.

```css
.child-one{
  display : block;
}

.child-two{
  display : none;
}

.parent:hover .child-one{
  display : none
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-one">
    text of child one
  </div>
  <div class="child-two">
    text of child two
  </div>
</div>
```